# Powershell Variables Output as Multiline text

Tags: powershell, variables

I was wondering if someone could please help me.

I work with a Helpdesk ticket system where sending an email to a certain email address, creates a job/ticket. I am trying to simplify this by creating a script where I can input the subject and text of an email body into a variable in a script, and sends all this as an automated email.

The script used seems to work fine, but the multi line text copied into the variable for the email body, comes out all as a one line string of all the data copied on the email body when the email arrives in my inbox, not it the same format from which it was copied, with multiple lines.

I cant think of any way to make this output the same as what was copied and having trouble finding solutions with google.

Current Script as below:

```
Clear-Host
$HD_Email_Credential = Get-Credential

#Gather information to send in email Body
$Subject = Read-Host 'Please Enter the email subject here '
Write-Host = 'Please copy (Ctrl+C) in the Email Body and press Enter'
Pause
$EmailBody = Get-Clipboard -TextFormatType Text

#Define Email Parameters
$FromAddress = 'myemail@email.com'
$ToAddress = 'helpdesk@fakecorp.com'

$EmailParams = @{
    From       = $FromAddress
    To         = $ToAddress
    Subject    = "$Subject"
    Body       = "$EmailBody"
    SmtpServer = 'smtp.office365.com'
    Port       = 587
    UseSsl     = $true
    Credential = $HD_Email_Credential
}

#Send Email
Send-MailMessage @EmailParams
Write-Host "Email successfully sent to $ToAddress from $FromAddress" -ForegroundColor Green
```

Ive tried pasting (Ctrl + V) information into a Read-Host option for $EmailBody and it crashes the script pasting in multiline text.

```
#Gather information to send in email Body

$Subject = Read-Host "Please Enter the email subject here "
$EmailBody = Read-Host "Please enter in the Email Body "
```

When in the windows powershell IDE though and executing the script, it accepts the multiline text! but not "running the .PS1 script with powershell" as I need it to be.

Currently using Get-Clipboard as a potential solution, close as I can get so far.

Tried a here-string -

```
@"

$EmailBody

"@
```

but variable not outputting and data, even using double quotes "

I hope this has been explained ok. If someone could please help, that would be much appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: add `-Raw` to your `Get-Clipboard` call

Comment: Tried and running the script says there is nothing in the body variable ?
 I used $EmailBody = Get-Clipboard -FormatType Text -Raw

Send-MailMessage : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Body'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument
that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this
you can paste multilines and when done you just type "end"

```
$EmailBody  = [string]::Empty
$line = [string]::Empty
while ($true) 
{
    Read-Host "Type `"end`" to finish" | Set-Variable line
    if ($line -eq 'end') 
    { 
        break 
    }
    Set-Variable EmailBody -value ($EmailBody + "`n" + $line)
}
$EmailBody  = $EmailBody.trim()
```